# Looping twice is faster than looping once in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, loops

Here is a small test I did and the result surprised me: doing the same loop twice was approximately twice as fast as looping once. I am guessing it as because of memory access?

```
float* A = new float[1000000];
float* B = new float[1000000];
int h,w;
h = w = 1000;
CString txt;
double time1, time2;

time1 = Timer::instance()->getTime();
for(int j = 0; j < h; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++){
        A[i+j*w] = 1;
        B[i+j*w] = 1;
    }
}
time2 = Timer::instance()->getTime();
txt.Format(_T("Both in same loop = %f"),time2-time1);
AfxMessageBox(txt);

time1 = Timer::instance()->getTime();
for(int j = 0; j < h; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++){
        A[i+j*w] = 1;
    }
}
for(int j = 0; j < h; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++){
        B[i+j*w] = 1;
    }
}
time2 = Timer::instance()->getTime();
txt.Format(_T("Different loops = %f"),time2-time1);
AfxMessageBox(txt);
```

Comment: The execution time is probably dominated by memory access, and the second version looks much more cache-friendly.

Comment: Probably cacheing, but even if it weren't, I've seen this due to register management. It can better optimize a loop if what's in the loop is simpler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be CPU cache, but more likely it's the concurrent memory access. When you access `array1[x]`, and then immediately after that `array2[x]`, those are two very different locations in memory and it's difficult to optimize. However `array[0]`, `array[1]`, `array[2]` etc are all in contiguous memory and much more efficient to access. [Intel seems to agree](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/fortran/lin/compiler_f/optaps/fortran/optaps_code_arch_f.htm).

Comment: Even 4 variables and 4 loops is twice as fast as one loop with the 4 variables. Is there any case in which it would be worth putting more than one variable in the same loop ?

Comment: I can't imagine there would be, I mean in both cases you're accessing the exact same memory but when they're all in their own loops you're doing it in a more efficient manner.

Answer (score 4):

Might want to add an extra, untimed, loop before you start measuring time.

Comment: Done, but still much faster to use 2 loops.

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of cache. In the loop where you access both `A` and `B`, the CPU is forced to load both in the cache, therefore having less elements of each array in it. In the other loops, the cache is full of `A`'s (or `B`'s) elements, so cache misses happen less often.

Comment: You could test that theory by making the size of the arrays much smaller, and see if you still get the same result.

Comment: I doubt that this is correct since each element of the arrays are only written to once. If the loop were repeated then I might expect the cache performance to matter.

Comment: @Chris Hopman: sorry but I don't get your point. The cache contains more than just one array's element

Comment: @BlackBear: Essentially you always get a cache miss on the first access of an element (ignoring prefetching). Since the loops access each element only once there should be the same cache misses regardless of if its done as one loop or two.

Comment: Another possibility would be that the arrays are still in the cache after the first loop, in which case there would be less/no cache misses in the second/third.

Comment: @Chris Hopman: yes but the cache, when accessing 2 arrays, will hold less elements of each array, so there will be more misses

Comment: @BlackBear: I don't think that's the case. In fact, a 4KB cache will perform the same here as a 4MB cache. As you go through the loop, you get a cache miss when you first access a word and then you don't care when that word gets evicted because you don't access it again.

Comment: @Chris Hopman: yeah got it, didn't considered array size vs cache size

Comment: @BlackBear: I should clarify a bit. I agree that when accessing 2 arrays the cache will hold less elements of each. Just that in this case it doesn't matter how much of the array fits in the cache.